# How to use newrelic.createBackgroundTransaction without a handle function

Tags: node.js, logging, newrelic

I am looking into using newrelic APM to monitor certain parts of our codebase.

I want to watch transactions that are not simple HTTP calls, but background processes. These transactions are completed by worker processes and we want to monitor them in the main part of the app.

Pseudo code:

```
var fork = childProcess.spawn('node', ['--harmony', 'path-to-worker.js', args]);
fork.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  // a finished transaction
  // this fires most likely more than once
});
```

We basically need something like [newrelic.createBackgroundTransaction()](https://github.com/newrelic/node-newrelic#newreliccreatebackgroundtransactionname-group-handle) that can log a transaction immediately, without having to pass it a function to execute and time (I can do that myself).

Can I do something like this on the free tier of newrelic?